# Thrift Example in Lua

Tags: lua, thrift

Where can I find an example of how to load a Thrift file in lua?

My code so far is below. I can't figure out how to create memory buffer. It fails at TMemoryBuffer:new()

```
local fullpath = FullPath("ConfigData.bin")
local infile = io.open(fullpath, "rb")
local buffer = infile:read("*all")

local transport1 = TMemoryBuffer:new()
transport1:resetBuffer(buffer)
local transport = TFramedTransportFactory:getTransport(transport1) local protocol = TBinaryProtocolFactory:getProtocol(transport)
flux.assert(protocol)
Data:read(protocol)
```

Comment: How does it fail? What did you expect? What have you tried? On what system does the code (not) run? This question is potentially missing a lot of information.

Comment: [Please add all required information. For starters, this includes the error message instead of "*it fails at ...*"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Who's "it"? What does "it" do instead? It isn't that hard.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a perfectly reasonable, system-independent question easily solved by exactly what I was asking for - an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
local fullpath = FullPath("ConfigData.bin")
local infile = io.open(fullpath, "rb")
local buffer = infile:read("*all")

TMemoryBuffer:resetBuffer(buffer)
local protocol = TBinaryProtocolFactory:getProtocol(TMemoryBuffer)
Data:read(protocol)
```